# Arrange Compose LazyVerticalGrid items to right

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

By default, LazyVerticalGrid items are aligned to left. Is there any way we can arrange items to right, something like this?

[image]

I have tried using `horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End` but this is not working.

```
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(gridHeight.dp)
            .padding(horizontal = 20.dp),
        columns = object : GridCells {
            override fun Density.calculateCrossAxisCellSizes(
                availableSize: Int,
                spacing: Int,
            ): List<Int> {
                val firstColumn = (availableSize - spacing) * 3 / 5
                val secondColumn = availableSize - spacing - firstColumn
                return listOf(secondColumn, firstColumn)
            }
        },
        userScrollEnabled = false,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End
    ) {
         //Item }
```

Comment: Is it just about the last (not filled) row, or should the first item of the list be in top right position, second top left, ...?

Comment: It's just the last row. So, instead of placing the last item to the left, I need it on the right side. Updated the image for your reference.

Comment: Just played around with it and I can't find a simple solution to this problem. You should probably report a bug to google, because I think that `horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End` should do exactly that. Meanwhile, the only solution I can think of is to add empty item to the last row

Comment: I have one solution but it has limitations. 1) it is using lazycolumn 2) width should give manually. if these are okay will post

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using a custom gridlayout using Row and Column